# How to delete content between text?

Tags: html, regex, sed, grep

I want to delete all `<scripts>` in all html files in all subfolders.
I can't find the correct version of the line

regular expression: `<script[\w\W]*?</script>`

here's how it looks in the line for my reasons:

```
find . -type f -name «*.html» -exec sed -i 's/<script[\w\W]*?</script>//g' {} \;
```

I also tried it on every screening down to:
`\<script\[\\w\\W\]\*\?\<\/script\>`

this doesn't work

There is another option

`find -type f -name \*.html | xargs sed -i '/\<script/,/\<\/script\>/c\ '`

but it deletes all the contents of the page from the first script to the last. 
All I need to delete only `<script ....</script>`

Maybe grep can do it?

Comment: Are all your `<script>...</script>` located on the same line? I would recommend you to use a XSLT on your html files though that's the cleanest way

Comment: Regular expressions are catastrophically ill-suited to parsing structured formats. This is basically an amplification of the preceding comment.

Comment: Are you really using guillemets `«*.html»` to quote shell meta characters? That will never work. You MUST use ASCII double quotes, ASCII single quotes, or backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Using regex to parse HTML or XML files is essentially not done (see [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)). Tools such as `sed` and `awk` are extremely powerful for handling text files, but when it boils down to parsing complex-structured data — such as XML, HTML, JSON, ... —  they are nothing more than a sledgehammer. Yes, you can get the job done, but sometimes at a tremendous cost.  For handling such delicate files, you need a bit more finesse by using a more targetted set of tools.

In case of parsing XML or HTML, one can easily use [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php).

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//script'
```

However, As HTML pages are often not well-formed XML, it might be handy to clean it up a bit using [`tidy`](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). In the example case above this gives then :

```
$ tidy -q -numeric -asxhtml --show-warnings no <file.html> \
  | xmlstarlet ed -N "x=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" \
               -d '//script'
```

where `-N` gives the XHTML namespace if any, this is recognised by

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

In the XHTML output of `tidy`.

Answer (score 2):

**Example of file:**

```
$ more input.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="example"></p>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = "My first JavaScript code";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Example of stylesheet:**

```
$ more removescript.xsl 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//script" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Command:**

```
$ xsltproc --html removescript.xsl input.html 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="example"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Explanations:**

The stylesheet will copy every single node and attribute, when it matches the node `<script> </script>` it will do nothing (no copy) therefore those nodes will be removed in the result.

Comment: Very nice alternative to xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple solution:

`find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec perl -0 -i -pe 's/<script.*?script>//gs' {} \;`